# Not getting response back in webapp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new in app script and trying to make simple webapp, but I am not getting any return from apsscript when webpage is loading, it is returning null instead

Here is the code:-

```
function loadTest()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssname = ss.getSheetByName('Sales');
  const range = ssname.getDataRange().getValues();
  return range
}
```

Client side Code:-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(event)=>{
         const startTime = new Date()
         google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(e){
         console.log(e)
         }).loadTest()
       })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to return prohibited elements like `date` from server side of webApp, which is making request fail and client getting **null** as a return .

Try following modification, changing this:-

```
const range = ssname.getDataRange().getValues();
```

To  this :-

```
const range = ssname.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

**Reference:-**

[Parameters and Return Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)